# Ошибка в запросе SQL (MySql 8.0.17) | C#

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, syntax

Я пытаюсь сделать **SELECT * FROM member WHERE id = 627528083** запрос к базе данных, но мне выдаёт ошибку синтаксиса **в строке 41**, почему?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Пожалуйста, приводите код текстом, а не картинкой.

Comment: Попробуйте числа в ID взять в одинарный кавычки (апострофы)

Comment: Версия сервера часом не 8.0.17?

Comment: @Akina да, абсолютно верно, версия сервера 8.0.17

Comment: Поздравляю, Шарик, ты попал... начиная с этой версии, слово `member` - резервированное. Теперь лопать все свои структуры и коды, и квотируй имя этой таблицы...

Comment: @Akina а, спасибо, но это совсем не проблема, я эту бд делал минут 10ть а код только начал писать, переделать не составит труда. Если поможет - отпишусь.

Comment: @Akina да это помогло, правда сервер конечно какой-то странный раньше делал на нём всё было ок, щас не может прога подсоедениться к нему, ну то уже мои проблемы, спасибо. Предлагаю тебе написать ответ, что б ты баллы получил.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Начиная с версии MySQL 8.0.17 слово **"member"** [зарезервированое](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/keywords.html), по-этому мне кидает ошибку в запросе **"SELECT * FROM *members* WHERE id = 61486942"**. Спасибо за ответ [@Akina](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/229437/akina).